# How to connect to Kubernetes using ansible?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I want to connect to Kubernetes using Ansible. I want to run some ansible playbooks to create Kubernetes objects such as roles and rolebindings using ansible k8s module. I want to know if the Ansible K8s module is standard Kubernetes client that can use Kubeconfig in the same way as helm and kubectl.

Please let me know how to configure Kubeconfig for ansible to connect to K8s cluster.

Comment: Did you give the documentation a look? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/k8s.html https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html

Comment: I am newbie to ansible..If I just install ansible in my local machine and try to connect to EKS cluster following this link ,will that suffice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically [specify the `kubeconfig` parameter in the Ansible YAML file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html#parameter-kubeconfig). (It defaults to `~/.kube/config.json`). For example:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars_files:
    - vars/main.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Deploy my app secrets.
      k8s:
        definition: '{{ item }}'
        kubeconfig: '~/.kube/config'
        state: present
      loop: "{{ lookup('template', 'myapp/mysql-pass.yml') | from_yaml_all | list }}"
      no_log: k8s_no_log
   ...
```

You can also make it a variable:

```yaml
    ...
    - name: Deploy my app secrets.
      k8s:
        definition: '{{ item }}'
        kubeconfig: '{{ k8s_kubeconfig }}'
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at more complicated example:
https://github.com/skosachiov/ansiblecd

The example describes in detail the preparation configuration of several clusters (~/.kube/config), storage of secrets in the ansible vault, organization of github collaboration using GitOps practices and github Actions.

...A commit to the devel git branch automatically rolls out changes to the devel environment, a commit (merge from devel) to the prod branch makes changes to the prod environment, and so on.

Answer (score -2):

Thankyou..It worked for me..I tried the below.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: Create a k8s namespace
     k8s:
      kubeconfig: '~/Documents/sample-project/eks-kubeconfig'
      name: testing1
      api_version: v1
      kind: Namespace
      state: present
      state: present
```